# How to compress a image size to a desired file size in KBs using ffmpeg or python or Ubuntu Command line?

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to take a screenshot from a udp stream.
Due to varying bit rates while transmission, the captured screenshot has different file size everytime.400KB,500KB..Even though it is screenshot of a same static page.

Is there a way to get a specific file size every time, in ffmpeg?

Or is there a command to convert a captured file to the desired KB using Python or through Ubuntu terminal?

Here is the command I'm using.

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@XXX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX -vframes 1 -q:v 1 test.png
```

I also tried the following commands in terminal, but it did nothing.

```
convert -define jpeg:extent=100kb test.png output.png
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a highest size value and everything below that value stays is, or do you want all files to have the same size? I don't see why you'd want to do the latter.

Comment: @Reti43 I want all file sizes to be of same size.The later case.Generally most of the files are of same size,different in only few kbs(ex:406.2KB,415.6KB....).So I need to compress them into one average size(say 400KB).

Comment: I'm not aware of any compression algorithms that compress data based on the output file size. They generally operate on how lossy the process will be, or how much memory/time it'll take to complete the operation. Why are you after such uniformity?

Comment: There is a system(Not developed by me),which takes generated output files in a particular file size.I guess I need to point out the same to them,what you have mentioned here about compression algorithm.

Comment: Setting the `jpeg:extent` is not going to help with a PNG, only JPEGs. I know of no similar option for PNGs.

Comment: Oh thanks.I'll try that and update here.Such a stupid mistake,I didn't notice.
edit:-It doesn't work.

Comment: png:extent didn't work nor any of the other solutions I found on Google.Now we have resorted to some other approaches,instead of compressing file size.